# Installing JDK and Python and setting the PATH variable on Windows 7

Tags: python, installation, java, windows-7-x64

I recently installed Java's JDK and Python in my Windows 7 system. I wanted to access both programs from the command line (whether it be cmd or cygwin) so I used the PATH global variable and entered the path to my JDK. What can I do so that python and JDK are accessed by PATH? What I am doing now is changing the PATH variable every time.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm confused.  Are you switching out the paths between the JDK and Python?  If that's the case, you can have both paths set in your system's `PATH` variable.  Example: `C:\jdk-install\;C:\python-install`

Answer (score 1):

- Right click on "My Computer"
- Choose "Properties"
- Click on "Advanced System Settings"
- Click on "Environment Variables"
- Find PATH and set it appropriately

Note that only processes started after you change the path will see the change.

Comment: If I change the path, then I will have to use only one or the other